# Fetch list of Facebook Friends those birthdays in current month

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am writing an app in which I am *fetching list of all my Facebook friends* with their *Name, DOB and Profile Picture*.

So here my question is how can i fetch list of friends those birthdays in current month.. only **list of current month friends birthdays**....

*Code:*

```
 public class FriendListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements SectionIndexer 
{
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;   
    private GetProfilePictures picturesGatherer = null;
    FriendsList friendsList;
    private String[] sections;

    Hashtable<Integer, FriendItem> listofshit = null;

    public FriendListAdapter(FriendsList friendsList) 
    {
        this.friendsList = friendsList;
        sections = new String[getCount()];
        listofshit = new Hashtable<Integer, FriendItem>();
        for (int i = 0; i < getCount(); i++) 
        {
         try 
            {
                sections[i] = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("name").substring(0);
                sections[i] = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("birthday").substring(1);
            }
         catch (JSONException e) 
            {
                sections[i] = "";
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "getJSONObject: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        if (picturesGatherer == null) 
        {
            picturesGatherer = new GetProfilePictures();
        }
        picturesGatherer.setAdapterForListener(this);
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(friendsList.getBaseContext());
    }

    public int getCount() 
    {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "getCount()");
        if (jsonArray == null)
            return 0;
        return jsonArray.length();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) 
    {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "getItem()");
        return listofshit.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) 
    {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "getItemId()");
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "getView(" + position + ")");

        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
        try 
        {
            jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(position);
        } catch (JSONException e) 
        {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "getJSONObject: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        FriendItem friendItem;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.single_friend, null);
            friendItem = new FriendItem();

            convertView.setTag(friendItem);
        }
        else {
            friendItem = (FriendItem) convertView.getTag();
        }

        friendItem.friendPicture = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.picture_square);
        friendItem.friendName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        friendItem.friendDob = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dob);
        friendItem.friendLayout = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.friend_item);

        try {
            String uid = jsonObject.getString("uid");
            String url = jsonObject.getString("pic_square");
            friendItem.friendPicture.setImageBitmap(picturesGatherer.getPicture(uid, url));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "getJSONObject: " + e.getMessage());
            friendItem.friendName.setText("");
            friendItem.friendDob.setText("");
        }

        try {
            friendItem.friendName.setText(jsonObject.getString("name"));
            friendItem.friendDob.setText(jsonObject.getString("birthday"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "getJSONObject: " + e.getMessage());
            friendItem.friendName.setText("");
            friendItem.friendDob.setText("");
        }

        listofshit.put(position, friendItem);

        return convertView;
    }

    public int getPositionForSection(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public int getSectionForPosition(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public Object[] getSections() {
        return sections;
    }
}
```

==================================================================================

```
    public static void requestFriends(FacebookRequest facebookRequest) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "requestFriends(" + ")");
    String query = "select name, birthday, uid, pic_square from user where 
      uid in (select uid2 from friend where uid1=me()) order by birthday_date";
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("method", "fql.query");
    params.putString("query", query);
    FacebookUtility.asyncRunner.request(null, params, 
    new FacebookRequestListener(FacebookRequestListener.FRIENDS, facebookRequest));
}
```

Comment: how you getting the list of all birthdates of friends..

Comment: above code is for what data you are getting now what you sending...
@Liza

Comment: after you getting birthdate You have to check (month) is currrent or not if it is current month then format it and display.

Comment: @Liza what exactly you want..?? just to show current month data...???

Comment: hi.. did you got the solution for that github project ?

Comment: k i will post the changed class as a answer.. just replace that code in your project.. your project will work. it will provide list of facebook friends birthdate, and this week birthdayte.. and current month birthdate.. seperately in the tabs..

Answer (score 0):

Change your current query:

```
String query = "select name, birthday, uid, pic_square from user where uid in (select uid2 from friend where uid1=me()) order by birthday_date";
```

To this:

```
String revisedQuery = "SELECT uid, name, pic_square, birthday_date FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()) AND birthday_date >= '01/01' AND birthday_date <= '01/31' ORDER BY birthday_date ASC";
```

The parameters in the `String revisedQuery`, `birthday_date >= '01/01'` and `birthday_date <= '01/31'` are what you will need to change to get *Birth dates* in a specific month.

Comment: @Liza: It is static in its current form. This is just to help you get your query straightened out. For making it dynamic, just check the current month and put them in the query.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED :**

Use thais query :-

```
"select name, birthday, uid, pic_square from user where uid in (select uid2 from friend where uid1=me()) AND MONTH(birthday) = MONTH(GETDATE()) order by birthday_date";

 public static void requestFriends(FacebookRequest facebookRequest) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "requestFriends(" + ")");
    String query = "select name, birthday, uid, pic_square from user where uid in (select uid2 from friend where uid1=me()) AND MONTH(birthday) = MONTH(GETDATE()) order by birthday_date";
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("method", "fql.query");
    params.putString("query", query);
    FacebookUtility.asyncRunner.request(null, params, 
    new FacebookRequestListener(FacebookRequestListener.FRIENDS, facebookRequest));
}
```